# how i can join array in MY Model

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, join

in controller i write :

```
public function kepala_keluarga($id = NULL)
{
  $table    = array('kelompok', 'pendidikan');
  $id_table = array('id_kelompok', 'id_pendidikan');

  $this->data['kepala_keluarga'] = $this->Anggota_model->get_by($table, $id_table);

  $this->load->view('something', $this->data);
}
```

in MY_Model i write :

```
public function get_by($table, $id_table)
{
   $this->db->select()
            ->from($this->_tabel_utama)
            ->join($table, $this->_tabel_utama.'.'.$id_table.'='.$table.'.'.$id_table, 'left');

   return $this->db->get()->result();
}
```

But `->join();` doesn't work? Thank's

Comment: Your get_by method can only take a single $table and $id_table at a time, not an array as you would have seen by the generated errors... So what is it exactly you are trying to achieve as there might be a better way to do it.

Comment: elaborate your question what you want to do join keyword use to join two tables not two array.

Comment: this is i want to do : ->join($table_utama, $table_utama.array($id_table) = array($table).array($id_table), 'left'). Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is the syntax need to follow.

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('blogs') // first table
$this->db->join('comments', 'comments.id = blogs.id', 'left'); // left join second table
// Produces: LEFT JOIN comments ON comments.id = blogs.id
```